# SCSS - Extend class dynamically

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

In Vue i have similar to

```
:style="{
            [`--chip-bg-hover`]: hoverColorValue,
            [`--chip-bg-active`]: activeColor,
            [`--chip-border-hover`]: borderHoverColorValue,
        }"
```

Then in SCSS

```
.chip:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 #00000026;
    @extend --chip-bg-active;
}
```

The problem is obvius. Can´t extend from to --chip-bg-active variable. Is a string also, but doesn't work right. So, anybody know the right way to extend  a class dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

`@extend` is used to extend **selectors** to share the declarations, but `--chip-bg-active` is a CSS variable and is a **value**. Think of it like trying to do `@extend #000` – this does not make sense. If you are trying to *use* the value of `--chip-bg-active`, you can use `var()` like this to get the value of the CSS variable:

```css
.chip:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 #00000026;
    background-color: var(--chip-bg-active);
}
```

Comment: Doesn´t work as i want. Chip-bg-active is a class not a value.

Comment: Could you then update the code in your example to show `--chip-bg-active` as a class? At the moment, `--chip-bg-active` is used in the `style` attribute of the element, which makes it a CSS variable. Otherwise, if `--chip-bg-active` is indeed a class, it needs to be defined somewhere that the calling `@extend` can find it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe can do something like this.

```
.chip:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 #00000026;
        $background-color: var(--chip-bg-hover);
        $border-color: var(--chip-border-hover);
        @if $background-color == 'defaultMarker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-defaultMarker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color1Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color1Marker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color2Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color2Marker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color3Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color3Marker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color5Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color5Marker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color4Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color4Marker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color6Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color5Marker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color7Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color6Marker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color8Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color7Marker-hover;
        } @else if $background-color == 'color9Marker-hover' {
            @extend .bg-color8Marker-hover;
        }
```

Comment: The `@if`s don't do anything here; the value of `$background-color` will always be `var(--chip-bg-hover)`, at the the time when Sass compiles the code. `var(--chip-bg-hover)` only changes at runtime, in the CSS in the browser internally.